# I repeated it after him

Tags: prepositions

*I repeated it after him.*

I would like to ask whether the preposition "after" is used properly. I want to express that I repeated  exactly the same words that he had said. The preposition "after" suggests that I repeated it after some period of time and I am not sure if I can use "after" in my context.

Comment: Repeat after me: "It is correct", with the possible exception of **it**.  *I repeated after him*.   **after** has multiple meanings. It can mean "in the manner of, following".

Comment: As @TRomano hints, "repeat after [pronoun]" is widely-recognized idiomatic phrasing. I think adding the "it" is fine. _Did you make up that joke? No, I repeated it after him._

Comment: But *to repeat it after him* (re-tell) is not (necessarily) the same as *to repeat after him* (repeat what he said verbatim).  Repeat after me: "I, J.R., being of sound mind...."  I don't mean to imply that the **it** is ungrammatical, just susceptible of being understood to mean something rather different.

Comment: I think it is fine and makes clear that you *immediately* repeated it after him to be sure you got it right. "After" does not imply that a longer period of time has elapsed in this case, only that it occurred after the first speaker said it. If you actually *need* to clarify, write "I immediately repeated it after him" instead.

Comment: @Mark Hubbard Yes, I repeated IT after him. The implication being that he just said it. Here's the bottom line: you either need a pronoun or noun after repeating OR you need a colon and you put in the actual words the person was/is repeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Longman Exams Dictionary gives one of the definitions of the verb **repeat** :

> "to say something that someone else has just said, especially in order to learn it:**repeat something after somebody**(Repeat after me...)

The verb is transitive. Your sentence is fine.

Comment: The word **repeat** alone isn't the crux of the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

> He told the lie and I repeated it after him.
>
> He told me to repeat after him, so I repeated after him. I repeated what he said verbatim.

In the first sentence, there is no implication that you followed his every word.  The introduction of the word **it** there can be understood to mean only that you too told the same lie, but not necessarily word for word.

The idiomatic form which means unambiguously "to repeat what someone has said, word-for-word, verbatim" has no pronoun:

> I *repeated after him* the words he spoke.
>
> He recited the oath and I *repeated after him*.

Answer (score -3):

Here's the point: If you say "I repeated after him" then you would have to say what you repeated.

If you say or write: /I repeated it after him/, you already know what the /it/ is.

Here is an example: /I repeated after him: 'Good behavior merits a reward'/.

/I repeated after him./ on its own is not grammatical.  What is repeated after a person has spoken has to be given in the sentence for it to be grammatical in the form without it.

Another example: I repeated after him the very words he said to my mother.

**The verb repeat is transitive, so you need a direct object**.

Comment: The verb phrase **repeat after** can be intransitive:  *How did you remember the oath? It is so lengthy!  -- The master of ceremonies recited it phrase by phrase, and I simply repeated after him.*

Comment: This really, really irritates me. /The master of ceremonies recited [the words] phrase AFTER phrase and I simply repeated THEM after him./ I am not going to argue with non-native speakers. End of story. Enjoy your downvoting. Too bad it's wrong.

Comment: Lambie, I hate to break it to you, but @TRomano isn't wrong, and if they aren't a native speaker, they're fluent enough for it not to matter. For example [He said, “As I repeated after General Porter, I recited a second oath in the back of my head...](http://www.presby.edu/about/2014/09/16/patriotism-at-pc/) or ["So I repeated after them, inviting Jesus into my bosom."](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/29/magazine/my-son-went-to-heaven-and-all-i-got-was-a-no-1-best-seller.html) Feedback on your answer is a good thing and should spark a discussion not an argument.

Comment: @ColleenV you are Making MY Point. Neither has: /I repeated after some person./ ***just hanging out there*** as a completge utterance. Just writing: /I repeated after him/ is  not grammatical in English. Both your examples IMPLY an object of the repetition.

Comment: Well then explain your point a little more clearly. In typical usage, it's perfectly OK to say "I repeated after her." or "Repeat after me." Something about what you're trying to express isn't making it across, so let's try to figure out why. The goal is to make an answer as clear and comprehensive as possible. If someone is saying you're wrong and you're not, the best response is to add support to your answer that shows you're correct. That is likely to give the non-native speakers more confidence in your answer and may get you some offsetting up-votes.

Comment: Who's the non-native speaker you're not arguing with, @Lambie? My network profile says "Pennsylvania" not "Transylvania".

Comment: *....desiring the witness to repeat after him...*  https://books.google.com/books?id=ECQwAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA110&dq=i+repeated+after+him&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQg96ZhL7RAhUBzSYKHfh5BjQQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=i%20repeated%20after%20him&f=false